# Problem when running a .jar on Linux Mint 21.1

Tags: java, linux, jar, linux-mint

Iḿ trying to run a jar file using `java -jar file.jar` and I get this message `[error] main:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
[error] main: java.awt.HeadlessException: 
[error] main: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set,
[error] main: or no headful library support was found,
[error] main: but this program performed an operation which requires it
```

I don´t know how to fix it, I tried `export DISPLAY=:0` but it doesn´t work.

EDIT:
I found out that I had also installed another java JDK version (11) and I tried to run it with that version, and it worked, but now I have another problem. The .jar that Iḿ trying to run (jedit.jar from Jason) says me that a file is 59.0 and JDK 11 only supports maximum 55.0 files. How can I install the JDK 17??

EDIT:
I installed JDK 17 and it worked.
And I have to say that clearly there`s a problem with java JDK 19, that was the version that I have installed apart from 11.

Comment: Did you install the full (headful) JRE or only the headless one? Check `dpkg-query 'openjdk*' |grep ^ii` if not certain.

Comment: I checked and I I only have the headless one. Should I install the headful?

Comment: Yes, to run GUI programs you must have a headful JRE. But it seems that in changing to 17 you actually got headful 17, which is good enough. (Actually 15 up -- if headful -- would be enough for classfile version 59, but 15 isn't on long-term support and 17 is, so using 17 is generally a better choice unless you actually need a newer version for some feature.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with Java JDK 19 version, I installed the 17 one and problem solved, I don´t know exactly why.